# Unable to access class property using __dict__ in Python 3.8

Tags: python, decorator, setter

I've two classes `test` and a child class `test2`, and I'm using a `@property` and a `setter` decorator to create the `brand` property. An example is shown below:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._brand = None

    @property
    def brand(self):
        return self._brand

    @brand.setter
    def brand(self, brand_name):
        self._brand = brand_name


class test2(test):
    def __init__(self, brand):
        super().__init__()
        self.brand = brand
        self.city = 'London'


ola = test2('Coca-Cola')
ola.brand = 'Coca-Cola'
dict1 = ola.__dict__
print(dict1)
```

I'm trying to get access to the `brand` property when using the `__dict__` method, but only `city` and the hidden `_brand` are appearing. I don't understand why this is happening, and how I can fix it... Thank you for any help!

Comment: `brand` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Answer (score 2):

`__dict__` is an object's *personal* dictionary. It contains things specific to that instance. It does *not* include instance methods or anything else defined on the class, and this includes properties.

Properties, like instance methods, are stored on the class. When you write

```
my_instance._brand
```

Python translates that to

```
my_instance.__dict__['_brand']
```

However, when you get a property, something different happens.

```
my_instance.brand
```

is actually equivalent to

```
type(my_instance).brand.__get__(my_instance, type(my_instance))
```

and the `property` class (which is what `brand` is an instance of) declares a `__get__` magic method that handles the actual call and invokes the function you wrote.

What happens when you write `foo.bar` is actually insanely complicated in Python. It's designed to always do what you expect, and the actual rules behind it do a ton of work on the backend to make the behavior always intuitive. The full rules are far too much to state in a single Stack Overflow answer. If you're really interested in the gritty details, I [wrote an extremely long article](https://gist.github.com/Mercerenies/df8fb4243d39f45615e1a7d10a66f011) about it several months ago as part of an answer to a similar question.

Comment: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/ is also a good resource for understand attribute access (explained as part of understanding the wider metaclass system).